# Shell-Script to join all CSV files in directory with two key-columns

Tags: shell, csv, join, awk

I'm struggling for a while now.

I have a directory with more than 5 CSV files. The idea is to join them all with a script (maybe with a loop?).

Example with only two files:

File1

```
1   ;   1.1   ; xyz
1   ;   1.2   ; abc
2   ;   2.1   ; gfa
```

File2

```
1   ;   1.1   ; dft
1   ;   1.2   ; asd
2   ;   2.1   ; qwe
```

Output file should look like this:

```
1   ;   1.1   ;   xyz    ; dft
1   ;   1.2   ;   abc    ; asd
2   ;   2.1   ;   gfa    ; qwe
```

In every CSV file, the first two columns are the "primary-key". I have tried it with join and awk but I don't get it (wrong approach?).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: add the join/awk code you tried to question... regarding sample, I'd suggest to add at least one line without feature cell.. also, lines are always in same order? if so, you could simply paste the files together along with using cut to get only the last field..

Comment: for ex: `pr -mts' ;' file1 <(cut -d';' -f3 file2)`

Comment: AND, in the future, you will want to use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input files:**

```
$ cat featureA 
SW1 ; 1.1 ; xyz
SW1 ; 1.2 ; abc
SW2 ; 2.1 ; gfa

$ cat featureB
SW1 ; 1.1 ; dft
SW1 ; 1.2 ; asd
SW2 ; 2.1 ; qwe
```

**Output:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{k=$1 OFS $2}FNR==NR{arr[k]=$3;next}k in arr{print k,arr[k],$3}' featureA featureB
SW1 ; 1.1 ; xyz; dft
SW1 ; 1.2 ; abc; asd
SW2 ; 2.1 ; gfa; qwe
```

**To address**

> I have a directory with more than 5 CSV files. The idea is to put
>   several CSV in this directory and run a script to join them all (maybe
>   with a loop?). The files are about switches.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{k=$1 OFS $2}{arr[k]=(k in arr?arr[k] OFS:"")$3}END{for(i in arr)print i, arr[i]}' feature*
SW1 ; 1.1 ; xyz; dft
SW1 ; 1.2 ; abc; asd
SW2 ; 2.1 ; gfa; qwe
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        FS=OFS=";"                    # i/p and o/p field separators
     }
     {
        k=$1 OFS $2                   # variable k used as key, 
                                      # field1 o/p field sep and field2
     }
     FNR==NR{                         # read featureA file 
        arr[k]=$3;                    # save 3rd field in array arr, with key being variable k 
        next                          # go to next
     }                
     k in arr{                        # read featureB file, if key exists in array arr
        print k,arr[k],$3             # print k, array value, and 3rd field
     }
    ' featureA featureB
```